# how to select a parent node having a specific child node?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is my **XML**,

```
<A>
    <B id = "1">
        <R>
        <C id="ABC" />
    </B>
    <B id = "2" >
        <R>
        <C id="ABC" />
    </B>
    <B id = "3" >
        <R>
        <C id="XYZ" />
    </B>
    <B id = "4">
        <R>
    </B>
    <B id = "5">
        <R>
    </B>
 </A>
```

I Need to select only **`<B>`** nodes that contains child element **`<C>`** and output should be like,

```
<B id = "1">
        <R>
        <C id="ABC" />
</B>
<B id = "2" >
        <R>
        <C id="ABC" />
</B>
<B id = "3" >
        <R>
        <C id="XYZ" />
</B>
```

`Descendants("B").Descendants("C")` is not helping.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What's your current C# code to read the XML file?

Comment: <R> hasn't got a closing tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse("xmlData");//or load...
var bElements = xml.Descendants("B").Where(x => x.Descendants("C").Count() > 0);
```

Alternatively, as suggested by Selman22, you ca use:

```
var bElements = xml.Descendants("B").Where(x => x.Descendants("C").Any());
```

Comment: Note that you can use `x.Descendants("C").Any()` instead of `x.Descendants("C").Count > 0`, and you miss the parentheses with `Count ` :)

Comment: @Selman22, thank you. Edited. I keep forgetting it's an extension... I blame it on IntelliSense :)

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse("data.xml");
var query = element.Descendants("C")
            .Where(c => c.Parent.Name == "B")
            .Select(c => c.Parent).Distinct()
            .ToList();
```